# Getting the source of information with Langchain

Tags: information-retrieval, langchain

I'm using langchain library to save the information of my company in a Vector Database, and when I query for information the results are great, but need a way to recover where the information are comming too - like source: "www.site.com/about" or at least "document 156". Do any of you know how to do that?

EDIT: Currently, I'm using `docsearch.similarity_search(query)`, what only return me the page_content, but metadata came empty

I'm ingesting with this code, but I'm totally open to change.

```
db = ElasticVectorSearch.from_documents(
        documents,
        embeddings,
        elasticsearch_url="http://localhost:9200",
        index_name="elastic-index",
    )
```

Comment: Can you show what code you're using to insert/query your vector database right now?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add metadata to each of those documents by setting `document.metadata` on each document to a dictionary. The dictionary could be something like `{"source": "www.site.com/about"}` or `{"id": "456"}`, to give some examples. Then, pass those documents to `from_documents()`.

Later, when you get a `Document` object back from one of the query methods, you can use `document.metadata` to get the metadata back.

Answer (score 2):

As a complement to [Nick ODell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/530160/nick-odell)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76369152/395857), here is a script showing the use of `metadata`:

```
import pprint
from langchain_community.vectorstores import FAISS
from langchain_community.embeddings import HuggingFaceEmbeddings
from langchain.docstore.document import Document

model = "sentence-transformers/multi-qa-MiniLM-L6-cos-v1"
embeddings = HuggingFaceEmbeddings(model_name = model)

def main():
    doc1 = Document(page_content="The sky is blue.",    metadata={"document_id": "10"})
    doc2 = Document(page_content="The forest is green", metadata={"document_id": "62"})
    docs = []
    docs.append(doc1)
    docs.append(doc2)

    for doc in docs:
        doc.metadata['summary'] = 'hello'

    pprint.pprint(docs)
    db = FAISS.from_documents(docs, embeddings)
    db.save_local("faiss_index")
    new_db = FAISS.load_local("faiss_index", embeddings)

    query = "Which color is the sky?"
    docs = new_db.similarity_search_with_score(query)
    print('Retrieved docs:', docs)
    print('Metadata of the most relevant document:', docs[0][0].metadata)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Tested with Python 3.10 with:

```
pip install langchain langchain_openai sentence-transformers langchain_community faiss-cpu
```